# Windows 8 doesn't support 1920x1080

Tags: windows, resolution

I have Windows 8, and after I installed it I found out that I can only use a 1600x900 resolution or less. I managed to make it 1920x1080 with the Nvidia control panel and its fine, but every game that I play I can't change the resolution to 1920x1080 and it really sucks.

Also Windows recommend using 1280x1024, but when in windows 7 it recommended using 1920x1080. Without the Nvidia control panel I even don't have 1920x1080 option...

Doesnt Windows 8 support a resolution above 1600x900?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You need to install the drives to be able to use the recommended resolution for your hardware.

Comment: @mor - please make questions clear instead of just ranting!

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, i installed the latest drivers (for windows 8) for my GTX550TI, And i don't have the option for 1920x1080 resolution. If i change to 1920x1080 by the nvidia control panel, i still can't have that resolution while playing games, and its really annyoing. Its like my windows doesn't support this resolution

Answer (score 1):

@mor did you see 1920x1080 in nvidia control panel? and you can choose it, and desctop resolution sets 1920x1080, but when you run еру Doom or another game like it you see 640x480 again?? how about looking resolution settings in Game options? of course, windows 8 supports high resolutions, maybe your game supports only low resolutions? Also, try to use another video card to run with it - coz some notebooks have 2 video cards (nvidia Optimus technology etc.) Just try click with right mouse button on your game shortcut, then choose which video adapter will be used with game (see image included in this answer, but i have Russian version). in any case, it's not windows trouble. maybe you`ll tell us, what game you are use and model of your monitor?[image]

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. When i had windows 7 it worked fine, 1920x1080 was recommended, now after i installed windows 8 and installed my drivers i didn't have that resolution. When i choose it via the nvidia control panel the desktop resolution do sets to 1920x1080 but when i enter a game, for example Guild Wars 2 (and some other games)  i don't have 1920x1080 option, and the highest is 1600x900 (or something like that). Thats why i don't think that the problem is with the graphic card or the monitor..

Comment: @mor - This is a driver problem.  This sounds like your nvidia control panel is not allowing the game access to the information required to determine what resolutions can be used.